# Why I can't Invoke from a different class?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, invoke

My problem is, I can't invoke a message into the `TextBox` and I can't understand why.

There is a main class and a second class, both with call to the other one.

Where is my error?

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Class_Test___Invoke
{
    public partial class MAINFORM : Form
    {
        public MAINFORM()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _INVOKER = this;
        }

        private MAINFORM _INVOKER;

        private static CLASS _CLASS = new CLASS();

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _CLASS._MESSENGER();
        }

        public void _LOGGING(string _MESSAGE)
        {
            if (InvokeRequired)
            {
                _INVOKER.Invoke(new Action<string>(_LOGGING), new object[] { _MESSAGE });
                textBox_ausgabe.AppendText(_MESSAGE);
                return;
            }
            else textBox_ausgabe.AppendText(_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
}

namespace Class_Test___Invoke
{
    class CLASS
    {
        private MAINFORM _MAINFORM = new MAINFORM();

        public void _MESSENGER()
        {
            _MAINFORM._LOGGING("Test");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The answer would depend on what language you are using, which you have not identified.

Comment: You need to pass the mainform instance to your class and not create a new form in the class constructor.

Comment: You're instantiating a new `MAINFORM` instance when `CLASS` is created. So `CLASS` has a reference to a different `MAINFORM` instance than `_INVOKER` does.

Comment: Oh dear.  Winforms is ruthlessly object-oriented, it will get you in trouble badly when that's still murky.  Nobody is going to teach you that here, focus a bit on how this happened.  Converted vb.net code maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming that the `_MAINFORM` you create in the `CLASS` constructor is the *same* instance as the form where the button was clicked, which is not the case. You have a chicken-and-egg problem. Your form creates a `CLASS`, and the `CLASS` creates a form. So now you have *two different forms*. (or two different `CLASS` instances since you don't show how the first form or `CLASS` is created)

You need to "connect" the form and the class, either by passing the form to the constructor as a parameter or by some other means.

Finally, I would encourage you to do some research on best practices for class and member names. It's a bit disconcerting for a seasoned C# developer to see names in all caps and prefaced by underscores.

Comment: Also disconcerting is the "Do I need to Invoke, if so, do that, *then repeat the same actions on what we know is an inappropriate thread*".

Comment: For reference, [the recommended naming guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines) (by Microsoft).